# How to make 3 divs align horozontally

Tags: css, html

This is my code and it ends up like this 
[[left img] [iframe] 
                     [right img]]
I need to align the code all horizontally so that it will go across the page. This is for a school project.

```
<div class="container">
<div width="33%" style="float: left;">
<img src="powder1.jpg" width="250" height="250"/>
</div>

<div>
<div width="23%">
<p>
We are located right next to <strong style="color: #ff0000;">Pizanos Pizzeria</strong> 
<br/> on <strong style="color: #ff0000;">North Loop Road</strong> in Brian Head, Utah.
</p>
</div>
<iframe width="33%" height="350" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" margin-height="0" 
margin-width="0" src="https://maps.google.com/maps?f=q&amp;source=s_q&amp;hl=en&amp;
geocode=&amp;q=briand+head+Ut&amp;aq=&amp;sll=39.235867,-94.42591&amp;
sspn=0.16354,0.338173&amp;ie=UTF8&amp;hq=&amp;hnear=Brian+Head,+Iron+County,+Utah&amp;
t=m&amp;ll=37.694433,-112.84652&amp;spn=0.002971,0.00456&amp;z=17&amp;output=embed">
</iframe><br /><small><a href="https://maps.google.com/maps?f=q&amp;source=embed&amp;
hl=en&amp;geocode=&amp;q=briand+head+Ut&amp;aq=&amp;sll=39.235867,-94.42591&amp;
sspn=0.16354,0.338173&amp;ie=UTF8&amp;hq=&amp;hnear=Brian+Head,+Iron+County,+Utah&amp;
t=m&amp;ll=37.694433,-112.84652&amp;spn=0.002971,0.00456&amp;z=17" style="color:#0000FF;
text-align:left">View Larger Map</a></small>
</div>

<div width="33%" style="float: right;">
<img src="powder2.jpg" width="250" height="250"/>
</div>
```

How can I fix this?!

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should be doing this structure in an external stylesheet and not inline. About the problem, only one of your boxes has `float:left;`, you need that on the three of them.

The proper solution would be: http://jsbin.com/ERiSeNI/2/edit

Answer (score 0):

You need to float your center div as well (and set iframe width to 100%), see: http://jsfiddle.net/3LVjt/

```
<div style="float:left">...
```

Answer (score 0):

**Remove** all `Floats` you have applied,

Then apply this CSS:

```
.container {
    white-space:nowrap;
}
.container div {
    display:inline-block;
}
```

**[FIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/S5bKq/345/)**

Answer (score 0):

All of your styling should be in external stylesheets, but the solution for what you are trying to do should look like this:

```
<div class="container">
    <div style="float:left; width: 33%;">
        <img src="powder1.jpg" width="250" height="250" />
    </div>
    <div style="float:left; width: 33%;">
        <p>
            We are located right next to <strong style="color: #ff0000;">Pizanos Pizzeria</strong> 
            <br/> on <strong style="color: #ff0000;">North Loop Road</strong> in Brian Head, Utah.
        </p>
        <iframe height="350" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" margin-height="0" margin-width="0" src="https://maps.google.com/maps?f=q&amp;source=s_q&amp;hl=en&amp;
        geocode=&amp;q=briand+head+Ut&amp;aq=&amp;sll=39.235867,-94.42591&amp;
        sspn=0.16354,0.338173&amp;ie=UTF8&amp;hq=&amp;hnear=Brian+Head,+Iron+County,+Utah&amp;
        t=m&amp;ll=37.694433,-112.84652&amp;spn=0.002971,0.00456&amp;z=17&amp;output=embed">
        </iframe>
        <br />
        <small><a href="https://maps.google.com/maps?f=q&amp;source=embed&amp;
        hl=en&amp;geocode=&amp;q=briand+head+Ut&amp;aq=&amp;sll=39.235867,-94.42591&amp;
        sspn=0.16354,0.338173&amp;ie=UTF8&amp;hq=&amp;hnear=Brian+Head,+Iron+County,+Utah&amp;
        t=m&amp;ll=37.694433,-112.84652&amp;spn=0.002971,0.00456&amp;z=17" style="color:#0000FF;
        text-align:left">View Larger Map</a>
        </small>
    </div>
    <div style="float:left; width: 33%;">
        <img src="powder2.jpg" width="250" height="250"/>
    </div>
</div>
```